# Unable to find copy database option in SQL Server 2008 r2 right click menu

Tags: sql-server, database, copy

I am Unable to find copy database option in SQL Server 2008 r2 right click menu. Is there any extra tool that I need to install to see this option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Copy Database` option is not available in the Express version of Management Studio prior to 2012 SP1. Go get the [free, no-longer-license-encumbered 2012 version](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35579). Click download, then scroll to the bottom, and choose whichever SQLManagementStudio file is appropriate for your language and platform (hopefully 64-bit, and it has to be > XP).